# Why were only Jean Luc and Guinan so outright hateful to the Borg ("I Borg")?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I notice that the others were either against the plan to destroy the Borg (Beverly Crusher), or, even if for the plan, at the very least middle of the road and somewhat neutral in their feelings and less personal (Riker, Geordi, Troi). How come only Jean Luc and Guinan were filled with rage. Yes I understand what they did to Picard and Guinan's people. Yet the others, who had to deal with them in battle,  and lost many of their friends in Wolf 359, are not so angry. Is it that the Borg never hurt them on a personal level the way they did to Picard and Guinan?

Comment: Geordi was busily plotting to genocide their entire species

Comment: I think it's more of a "THIS borg didn't hurt me personally." Federation types have a hard time seeing the entire collective in a single being so, because Hugh didn't directly participate in the atrocities the Borg committed, they had a difficult time with the concept of making him patient zero for  a plague. That difficulty became more pronounced as he became an individual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98151/discussion-between-adamant-and-ellie-kesselman).

Comment: Worf was likely hateful toward the Borg the entire time.

Answer (score 14):

Picard is easy: the Borg violated him *personally*, not friends of his.

As for Guinan, the scope is very different. There were (according to Memory Alpha) 11,000 casualties at Wolf 359. Compare that to (emphasis mine)

> Around 2265, while Guinan wasn't present, this species was the victim of a major attack by the Borg, with all but a handful of El-Aurians being assimilated or killed by the Borg, and all El-Aurian cities being destroyed by them. (TNG: "Q Who", "Ensign Ro", "I Borg") **The El-Aurian fatalities numbered in the millions** and included Doctor Tolian Soran's family: his wife and children. (Star Trek Generations) On the other hand, by resisting when the Borg came to assimilate them, the El-Aurians defied their attackers' motto that "resistance is futile." (TNG: "I Borg") When **the El-Aurian homeworld was destroyed by the Borg**, the El-Aurian species was scattered throughout the universe but nevertheless prevailed. (TNG: "Q Who", "The Best of Both Worlds")
>
> -- https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/El-Aurian

Answer (score 1):

The main thing with the rest of the crew is they do not understand to the extent of which Picard or Guinan truly hate them. In "Best of Both Worlds", the crew's mission was to stop the Borg and, if possible, get Picard back.  That was their mission, and they cared more about achieving those goals vs seeing the Borg suffer or having a personal hatred toward them other than due to what they had done to Picard.  Picard and Guinan both have first hand experience with what the Borg can do, so when Hugh enters the picture, they simply do not care.  The rest of the crew is willing to entertain the possibility of Hue having sentience separate from the Collective, but Picard neither knows nor cares to know.  When he sees Hugh, he sees only what they have done to him and others like him.  Guinan only sees the destruction of her homeworld and the lives that were lost and devastated as a result.  For them, it's not about numbers, or the sheer magnitude, it is always about a personal hatred for the both of them.  The Borg, in their eyes, do not change, cannot be reasoned with, and certainly should not attempt to be reasoned with.  Both Guinan and Picard believe eliminating them is the ONLY option, and no other possibility is worth entertaining.

> (Crusher is treating the Borg inside the cell)
>
> WORF: Lower the forcefield.
>   (a medic enters the cell and the forcefield is raised again. Picard enters the Brig)
>
> WORF: Captain, the Borg is still unconscious.
>
> CRUSHER: He suffered massive internal injuries. We've been able to control the haemorrhaging, but some of the implants in his brain were damaged. I may have to remove them.
>
> PICARD: The Borg will die if they're removed permanently. Their brains grow dependent on the biochips.
>
> CRUSHER: Perhaps Geordi can construct some new implants.
>
> LAFORGE: They contain relatively straightforward programming, interface protocols. We have the files we downloaded after your experience, Captain. I think I can manage it.
>
> PICARD: Mister La Forge, do you know enough about Borg programming to alter the pathways to their root command structure?
>
> LAFORGE: I'm not sure, sir. The subroutines are pretty complicated. I'd probably have to study the data processing algorithms. It's the only way I could trace the access codes.
>
> PICARD: If we could get to the root command, we could introduce an invasive programming sequence through its biochip system and then return it to the hive.
>
> LAFORGE: The Borg are so interconnected it would act like a virus.
>
> PICARD: Which would infect the entire Collective. We could disable their neural network at a stroke.
>
> CRUSHER: Infect it? You make it sound like a disease.
>
> PICARD: Quite right, Doctor. If all goes well, a terminal one.

Later on, while Guinan and Picard are fencing

> GUINAN: I don't think I like this sport.
>
> PICARD: Last week when you scored two touches, you liked it well enough. Today you were dropping your foil. You kept letting me inside.
>
> GUINAN: Ah, but if I lift up, you lunge right underneath. Let's face it, you're just better at this than I am. I understand we have a guest on board.
>
> PICARD: Yes.
>
> GUINAN: Is that wise?
>
> PICARD: I'm not sure. I hope so.
>
> GUINAN: I thought I understood you, Picard, but I don't understand this.
>
> PICARD: It was an errand of mercy. He was injured, Doctor Crusher decided for humanitarian reasons to care for him.
>
> GUINAN: They're going to come after us, you know that. You, of all people, know that.
>
> PICARD: Shall we go again?
>   (after exchanging parries and thrusts, Guinan grabs her thigh in pain)
>
> PICARD: Are you all right?
>   (she disarms him and scores a touch)
>
> GUINAN: You felt sorry for me. Look what it got you.

Both Picard and Guinan are forced to look at the situation with Hugh subjectively, given what has happened to them.  Since the rest of the crew have not been affected first hand, they have the luxury of being able to weight the pros and cons of what should be done objectively.

Even when Picard is confronted by Troi about the situation, he tells her he is fine with everything, but at least for part of the conversation, he is saying things in a tone in which he is being dismissive and saying anything he can to shut her up and get her out of his head.

> PICARD: Come.
>
> TROI: Captain, I just wondered if there's anything you wanted to talk about.
>
> PICARD: I don't think so, Counsellor.
>
> TROI: I would have thought having a Borg on the ship would stir some feelings.
>
> PICARD: I'm quite recovered from my experience, thank you.
>
> TROI: Sometimes even when a victim has dealt with his assault there are residual effects of the event that linger. You were treated violently by the Borg. Kidnapped, assaulted, mutilated.
>
> PICARD: Counsellor. Counsellor, I very much appreciate your concern for me, but I can assure you it is quite misplaced. I have carefully considered the implications of having a Borg on this ship. I have weighed the possible risks, and I am convinced that we are doing the right thing. Now, I am quite comfortable with my decision.
>
> TROI: I see. Well, if at any point you want to talk more.
>
> PICARD: I shall certainly avail myself of your help.

All Quotes have been taken from a transcript of the episode as posted on [chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/223.htm) and further verified through [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/I_Borg_(episode))